# Function or algorithm for spectral peak interpolation

Tags: python, signal-processing, interpolation

I'm processing spectral data in python and want to know if there are any pre-built ways to find the true (or more accurate) peak value by interpolating.

An example of my data:

```
Frequency (Hz), Amplitude(mm/s)
16.5    0.168
16.75   0.124
17      0.527
17.25   0.678
17.5    0.201
17.75   0.080
18      0.025
```

represented in a plot:

[image: Data plotted]

I want to be able to use the raw data (circled) to estimate the red cross.

I've looked very briefly into scipy and numpy, but those interpolation methods look like they are designed to estimate values for gaps in data, or in-between data. In my case, i want to use values adjacent to a peak to better estimate the true value of that peak.

I've done this before using the following formulas but i feel like there's a better way.

[image: True Frequency formula]

for frequency where:

- x = previous frequency
- y = frequency of initial peak
- z = next frequency

and

[image: True Amplitude formula]

for amplitude where:

- x = previous amplitude
- y = Amplitude of initial peak
- z = next amplitude

Currently I'm holding all this data in a 2D array, but can change that if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Spectral data produced by a rectangular windowed DFT or FFT can be interpolated by Sinc kernels, which, if the original data was band-limited before sampling, will perfectly (within numeric limits) reproduce the exact spectral peaks.  See [Whittaker–Shannon reconstruction formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whittaker%E2%80%93Shannon_interpolation_formula).

For other windows, the interpolation kernel would be the transform of the window.

More practically, a n-tap windowed Sinc interpolation kernel will interpolate an estimate above typical instrument noise floors.  Use successive approximation to estimate the maxima.

For a smaller number of taps, some people use a 3-point parabolic interpolator.  See: https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/sasp/Quadratic_Interpolation_Spectral_Peaks.html

Comment: The only data i have to work with is like in my example. From this i don't know if i'll be able to implement any of the methods you suggested apart from the 3 point parabolic interpolator right?